# Словообразование: рассЫпать → рассыпАть

Tags: словообразование, морфемика

Существует пара глаголов:

- расс**ы**пать *(сов.)* и рассып*а*ть *(несов.)*

Согласно словарю Тихонова второе образовано от первого. При этом буквенный морфемный состав у них одинаковый. Какая в данном случае используется схема словообразования?

Answer (score 1):

["Русская грамматика"](http://rusgram.narod.ru/1384-1407.html) по этому поводу говорит следующее:

> § 1400. Вторичная имперфективация (переписать - переписывать) - это
>   образование глаголов несов. вида с суф. -ива-/-ва-/-а<sub>3</sub>- от различных
>   префиксальных глаголов сов. вида, мотивированных беспрефиксными
>   глаголами несов. вида (префиксальные глаголы в последующем описании
>   избираются для иллюстрации произвольно).
>
> 1) С морфом -ива-: выдумать - выдумывать, выздороветь -
>   выздоравливать, дорисовать - дорисовывать, взмахнуть - взмахивать,
>   пропахнуть - пропахивать, высмеять - высмеивать, отволочь -
>   отволакивать (разг.), выкрасть - выкрадывать, вкрутить - вкручивать,
>   задержать - задерживать.
>
> 2) С морфом -ва-: загнить - загнивать, задуть - задувать, вбить -
>   вбивать, дожить - доживать, добыть - добывать, отбыть - отбывать.
>
> 3) С морфом -а<sub>3</sub>-: **разрезать - разрезать, засыпать - засыпать,**
>   ввергнуть - ввергать, отозвать - отзывать, выгрести - выгребать,
>   вырасти - вырастать, дожать - дожимать, выявить - выявлять, закипеть -
>   закипать, прогнать - прогонять.
>
> Примечание. В некоторых описаниях видовое соотношение у глаголов
>   *разрезать - разрезать*, *засыпать - засыпать* **толкуется как выраженное
>   исключительно ударением. Однако у этих глаголов различаются также и
>   парадигмы спряжения: разрезать - разрежу, разрежешь... и разрезать -
>   разрезаю, разрезаешь...**